# Should https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/spam be modified?

Tags: discussion

Currently it reads like this:

> Questions tagged [spam]
>
> This is for flagged spam. Delete all other **flags** and insert this
>   **flag** when you see a post that is clearly and unquestionably spam so that people following other tags don't get spammed.

Should **tags** be used instead of **flags**?

Comment: NEVER use tags to ID spam.  **ONLY** flag spam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, tags should **not** be used for this.

A [spam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/spam) tag should be something to do with handling/removing/creating/etc spam (eg email) on Ubuntu, and not coerced to a meta-tag for doing something that is infinitely better done through flags.

**Edit:** It was only created an hour ago, apparently for purpose. I think the justification is far too weak (no, spammers are *not* going to select the spam tag). I've run it over with my digger.

Comment: TL;DR: NEVER use tags to ID spam.  **ONLY** use flags to ID spam.

Comment: **+1** just for running over SPAM with a digger...  **>:-)**