# Why do some of my tag [suggestions or creations] get rejected?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, suggested-edits

Please, I will really like to know why some of my tag suggestions or tag creations keep getting rejected for *(my personal opinion)* nothing?!

Meanwhile, it seems some could be needed and of important use. An example is a tag (`davinci`) I created when reviewing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143100/davinci-is-not-starting) question. I could clearly see that there was no alternative for the said DaVinci the user wanted to install on Ubuntu 19.04.

Can anyone give me more insight on this? I'll be grateful.

Comment: In a slightly unrelated note, I noticed that [you added a "Thanks" at the end of the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1143100/revisions) while editing. Please avoid adding any kind of pleasantries to the question (as they don't contain anything, increase noise instead), rather remove anything present. Refer to this: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16665/480481

Answer (score 5):

Tags are used to group questions that are similar or focused on a particular thing, like [boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boot). There have been multiple instances where you tried to create tags which do not serve long lasting benefit to the site. We don't really need such tags. I left a comment for you [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142036/undefined-reference-to-ssl-ctx-set-alpn-protos-in-ubuntu-14-04-2#comment1894021_1142036) regarding the same (I'm not sure if you saw that). So, please refrain from creating such tags. There are millions of apps/softwares out there. We can't have tags for each and every software. In the end such tags have to be destroyed using diggers.

A simple [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation) tag is enough for such questions.

Since you are >300 reputation user, it's your responsibility to help  community to decide which tags should be created. If you still feel these tags would benefit the site, feel free to ask a question on meta with your opinions that why are they needed.

Comment: Which kind of tags then should I create?

Comment: @YufenyuyVeyehDider That's a tricky question. It depends on the need. If you think there's a dire need of this tag, create that. Remember tags also help watchers.

Comment: @YufenyuyVeyehDider *Generic* tags, see [help/tagging](https://askubuntu.com/help/tagging): “[Y]ou should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.”

Comment: Diggers or daggers ;)

Comment: @DKBose To be precise both. We use daggers and [Oli runs over them using his digger](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18543/816190)